# Spring RestTemplate with rootUri return URI is not absolute error

Tags: java, spring, kubernetes, resttemplate, camunda

I have a `RestTemplate` that I build it with `RestTemplateBuilder`. I set the rootUri for builder. In below method (updateState1) sometimes I got the "URI is not absolute" error. For example when I called this method concurrently for 2 times I often got 1 error.

**EDIT and Solution**:
I use this `RestTemplate` in service task of camunda process. I launch this project in kubernetes container that has different timezone with the oracle database. When I add timezone variable every things work fine.

Spring boot version: 2.1.1.RELEASE

Here is my code:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class CoreServiceClient {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private static final String root = "http://localhost:8080/test/api/";

    public CoreServiceClient(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.rootUri(root).build();
    }


    public void updateState1(UpdateParam updateParam) {
        HttpHeaders headers = generateHeader();
        UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest(updateParam.getState());

        HttpEntity<UpdateRequest> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(updateRequest, headers);

        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                "/food/{id}/state",
                HttpMethod.PUT, httpEntity, String.class, updateParam.getId());

    }
    public void updateState2(String id) {
        HttpHeaders headers = generateHeader();
        UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest("done");

        HttpEntity<UpdateRequest> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(updateRequest, headers);

        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                "/food/{id}/state",
                HttpMethod.PUT, httpEntity, String.class, id);

    }
}
```

cuase (stacktrace):

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute
    at java.net.URI.toURL(URI.java:1088)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.createRequest(SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.java:145)
    at org.springframework.http.client.support.HttpAccessor.createRequest(HttpAccessor.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:730)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:669)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:578)
    at com.test.client.CoreServiceClient.updateState(CoreServiceClient.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor263.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:479)
    ... 85 more
```

Comment: what final URL do you have when calling `restTemplate.exchange` ?

Comment: I want to call "http://localhost:8080/test/api/food//{id}/state" but I got error. I added the cause exception. There isn't any URL in stacktrace.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `/` in root:

```
private static final String root = "http://localhost:8080/test/api";
```

RestTemplate accepts uriTemplate as long as they start with `/` so your root should be without it. if it doesn't start with `/` it will consider it as a full `URL`

Comment: what do you mean by sometimes?

Comment: For example when I run it 2 times (concurrently) the first run has no error but second has error. Sometimes everything is good or shometimes 2 calls have error.

Answer (score 1):

I try with the same code. I do not get this error. 
Spring boot version: `1.5.0.RELEASE`

Instead of POST, I tried with a GET API with same URL pattern.
The `/` at the end of the path does not matter.

```
@Component
public class CoreServiceClient {
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CoreServiceClient.class);
    private static final String root = "http://localhost:8080/test/api/";

    public CoreServiceClient(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.rootUri(root).build();
    }


    public void updateState(String id) {

        try {
            ResponseEntity<String> response =
                    restTemplate.exchange("/food/{id}/state", HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class, id);
            LOGGER.info("Resp: {}", response.getStatusCode());
            LOGGER.info("Resp: {}", response.getBody());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }


    }
}
```

I added a dummy controller with the same path:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test/api")
public class FooController {

    @GetMapping("/food/{id}/state")
    public ResponseEntity<String> fooState(@PathVariable String id) {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("EATING", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

To test, I added another controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/client")
public class CoreServiceClientController {

    @Autowired
    private CoreServiceClient client;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> goGet() {
        client.updateState("1001");
        return new ResponseEntity<>("HELLO", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine for me.

Log:

```
2019-01-15 23:23:19.870  INFO 22570 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.example.demo001.CoreServiceClient    : Resp: 200
2019-01-15 23:23:19.871  INFO 22570 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.example.demo001.CoreServiceClient    : Resp: EATING
```